# Single string in json to deserialze c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have following string in JSON

```
string IDS = "{\"IDS\":\"23,24,25,28\"}"
```

Now I need to convert this into c# string

I tried this

```
string id = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string>(IDS);
```

I want to get back this comma separated string in a string, but it throws error

> No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String

Any help what to do ?

Thanks

Comment: "it throws error" is never enough detail. It's also unclear whether those backslashes are actually in the string, or whether that's a source-code representation of the string. It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: you want to deserialize a string into a string ? no, you dont. you're expecting an array i guess. try "var id" instead of "string id" in your second line of code you shared.

Comment: I have posted the error

Comment: @Doruk, I also tried var id, but same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your json string is a Dictionary. Try it with something like this

```
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(IDS);
var mystring = result["IDS"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this solution using JSON.net:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string IDS = "{\"IDS\":\"23,24,25,28\"}";
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(IDS);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.IDS);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public string IDS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I love to work with Newtonsofts JSON.net, +1 for suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you are using the incorrect type string to deserialize, it should be a Dictionary as Matthias Burger mentioned. However you can use dynamic type,

```
string json = "{\"IDS\":\"23,24,25,28\"}";
var jobject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(json );
string ids = jobject["IDS"]
```